# Invoke-command does not run vbs script using cscript in powershell remote session

Tags: powershell, session

I try to execute my simple vbscript on the remote session using PowerShell. The script does not have any error and run successfully, but I notified the code not executed in remote session. is there any way how to solve this?

```
$session=New-PSSession -ComputerName "192.XXX.XX.XX"   -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("UserName",(ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force))) 

$status= Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock{ 

& cscript "C:\Data\test.vbs"
```

}

Comment: what do you get from `icm -session $session { test-path "C:\Data\test.vbs" }` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SantiagoSquarzon. its return empty.

Comment: No `true` or `false` ? Are you sure you're not assigning that to a variable ?

Comment: i am sorry about my earlier observation . The script seems stuck when executed.